# Is it abnormal that out-of-sample fit is better than in-sample?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting

I'm using [Eureqa](http://www.nutonian.com/products/eureqa/), as machine learning tool to fit a formula to my data. I found out that the formula fits my test data better than my training data! Is this abnormal?

Comment: It's unlikely, but the test data is just a finite sample too. Entirely possible to get a good score. Other more malign reasons might include things like the training data being big enough to include more weird observations. While the test data might be smaller and happen not to have any members of the awkward squad in it.

Answer (score 5):

It is unusual but could happen. First of all, you have to realize that the model usually is only approximately able to mimic the data. How well the model fits the data can vary for different domains for the values of the predictor variables. For instance, suppose that variable $y$ is explainable by a linear function of $x$ plus noise. Suppose $y$ values were measured for $0 < x < 20$ and these data is divided into the training set with $M_\text{train}=\{(x,y):x<10\}$ and test data $M_\text{test}=\{(x,y):x\geq10\}$. If the noise is bigger for the training set ($x<10$) you can still get an accurate estimation of the slope parameter for the whole domain of $x$. Since the model is good it also predicts the $y$ values in the test set well and furthermore, because the noise term is smaller for the test set, also the prediction error (out-of-sample error) for the test set is smaller. Summarized:

If the model is a good description of reality and the noise (e.g. measurement errors) in the training set is larger than in the test set, the out-of-sample error (prediction error for the test set) can be smaller than the in-sample error (description error for the training set).

Whether this behaviour emerges also depends in the way the test set and the training set is constructed. If both sets are constructed by a random process picking elements from the same population and if this procedure is performed several times to estimate the out-of-sample error, then the out-of-sample error should not be smaller than the in-sample error. Alternatively, if the training set was obtained by one inaccurate measurement and the test set by a more accurate one, the error for the test data could be smaller than for the training set, of course under the assumption of a good model.

Answer (score 0):

A more specific explanation exists **if your feature set is sparse** it can generate the scenario George alluded to above.  This is especially true if your training set does not represent your population categories. If you are dealing with sparse data I might suggest building a **stratified K-fold cross-validation**. It will probably solve your problem.  You can find additional information elsewhere, but it basically attempts to include the same proportion of categories in your records across the train and test.